# Can a contact have more than 5 websites?

Tags: contacts

Apologies if I'm missing something simple...

I want to add about 10 websites to a contact, but after I add five, I no longer get an "Add" button, and can't figure out how to add more.

[image: five website limit (from d46.demo.civicrm.org)]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick workaround which I can see is you can easily add `n` number of websites for a contact from the Contact Edit Form (Click Edit on the Contact Summary Page).
`<site_name>/civicrm/contact/add?reset=1&action=update&cid=<contact_id>`.

This is restricted to a count of 5 (may be a bug) in Inline Edit mode according to the [code written here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/templates/CRM/Contact/Form/Inline/Website.tpl#L40).

Comment: That workaround is a big help, thanks so much!